# Concept of a asymmetric mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

There is one thread called "MThread" and 20 threads called "HThread_01"..."HThread_20". I'm looking for something akin to a mutex m with the following properties:

*If m.lock() is called from "MThread" the 20 "HThreads" will be blocked.*

*If m.lock() is called from one of the 20 "HThreads" only "MThread" will be blocked but not the other "HThreads".*

Is there a lightweight concept in C++ (not boost) that would allow for this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you're looking for something similar to a single-writer multiple-reader mutex. I unfortunately can't point you to one because I'm not too familiar with them

Comment: I think you can use `std::shared_mutex`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex)  fits your use case. A shared_mutex offers both exclusive and shared locking.

```
std::shared_mutex mut;
```

In MThread you would use `mut.lock()` to gain exclusive acces

In MThread_01 ... MThread_20 you would use `mut.lock_shared()` to gain shared access.

Comment: caveat: shared_mutex is c++17 (proposed). From c++14 we have std::shared_timed_mutex http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for!